# What's the easiest way to use infiniband from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, driver, infiniband

I've got two computers with Mellanox ConnectX VPI MT26428 infiniband cards running Windows 7 with drivers installed. What is the easiest way to start doing message passing (e.g. via MPI) from .NET?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MPI, configure MPI to use IB for message passing. Just write an MPI program and execute it. If your MPI is configured properly, it will preferentially use IB.
You can also use VERBS API to use IB directly. VERBS is analogous to TCP.